# Delete registry string that contains specific value

Tags: powershell

I am trying to delete registry string that contains value “Palo Alto Networks”

```
Path: HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-484763869-1659004503-1644491937-15773\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\UFH\SHC
String: 61
Value: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Palo Alto Networks\GlobalProtect\GlobalProtect.lnk
C:\Program Files\Palo Alto Networks\GlobalProtect\PanGPA.exe
/noshrink
```

I want the script to delete string “61” if it detects value “Palo Alto Networks” in it.

This is the code that I think close to what I aim.

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path $SearchBase |
    Where-Object {
        $_.$RegKeyValueName -match $RegKeyValueDataPattern
    } |
        Remove-ItemProperty -Name $RegKeyValueName
```

However, $RegKeyValueName is random. It could be other than 61.
My aim is if $RegKeyValueDataPattern match, it will delete the $RegKeyValueName

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add your code to your question.

Comment: I have added the code, Please assist

Comment: Do you want to delete the key or the value? If it's the value you should take a look at [Remove-ItemProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-itemproperty?view=powershell-5.1) ... pay special attention to the examples! ;-)

Comment: Hi Olaf.
I want the script to scan they key. If it detects value "Palo Alto Networks", the script will delete the string that hold the value.

I have checked the page. It just showing how to delete Key or string directly. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I'm not completely sure what exactly you like to delete. It might help you for the next time when you take a look at the following Info: [Structure of the Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sysinfo/structure-of-the-registry).

If you like to get the registry key values and you know the name you can use following syntax:

```
$SearchBase = 'REGISTRY::HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-484763869-1659004503-1644491937-15773\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\UFH\SHC'
$RegKeyValueName = '61'
$RegKeyValueDataPattern = 'Palo Alto Networks'

Get-ItemProperty -Path $SearchBase
```

If you're looking for a specific value you can either specify the name ...

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path $SearchBase -Name $RegKeyValueName
```

... or filter the output with a Where-Object ...

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path $SearchBase |
    Where-Object {
        $_.$RegKeyValueName -match $RegKeyValueDataPattern
    }
```

If you like to delete only the data of the value you can use [Set-ItemProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-itemproperty?view=powershell-5.1) and provide an empty string ...

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path $SearchBase |
    Where-Object {
        $_.$RegKeyValueName -match $RegKeyValueDataPattern
    } |
        Set-ItemProperty -Name $RegKeyValueName -Value ''
```

.... or if you like to delete the complete value you can use [Remove-ItemProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-itemproperty?view=powershell-5.1) ...

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path $SearchBase |
    Where-Object {
        $_.$RegKeyValueName -match $RegKeyValueDataPattern
    } |
        Remove-ItemProperty -Name $RegKeyValueName
```

.... and if you don't know the name of the value you like to delete you can use the following code scnippet:

```
Get-Item -Path $SearchBase |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Property |
        Where-Object {
            (Get-ItemProperty -Path $SearchBase -Name $_ ) -match $RegKeyValueDataPattern
        } |
            ForEach-Object {
                Remove-ItemProperty -Path $SearchBase -Name $_
            }
```

Comment: Hi Olaf.
Thanks for the response. The last code you provide I think is the closest one. I have edit code in my main question. Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: @MuhammadSuhailAsrulsani Ahhh ... I guess I got what you mean ... I added another code snippet. Try please.

Comment: You are awesome. its working. thanks for other code you provide :)